# Enabling word completion by ESC key

Tags: macos, shortcut

In Cocoa applications (for instance, TextEdit) there used to be a completion functionality by which, pressing the <kbd>esc</kbd>, or <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> (apparently, it depends on Mac OS X versions), a list of possible completions for the word being typed appears. In latest versions, up to El Capitan, it worked with just <kbd>esc</kbd>; in macOS Sierra, apparently, it has been reverted to <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>.

Although I know that someone didn't like the use of just ESC, I found it very handy. Is there a way to enable it?

I tried defining it in System Preference > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts, but it seems not to accept <kbd>esc</kbd> alone as a shortcut.